# Server files location

Tags: bigcommerce

In bigcommerce, How can I code dynamically?

I am unable find folder location for server side files.

I have seen only HTML, CSS and .js files.

I can't see php or server side files.

In between I have seen something like,

`%%SNIPPET_HomeNewProducts%%`,

a text inside double percentage, which I can't understand?

Answer (score 2):

I work at Bigcommerce. As a SaaS platform, you do not have root-level PHP file access. You can modify your store using CSS, HTML, Javascript and Jquery. We also have a very robust API. Check out the documentation here. http://bigg.cm/HuIJK6

In addition, we also have a great themes documentation guide, which explains many of the global variables, snippets, and panels. http://bigg.cm/12Y6Bdf

If you have any questions, feel free to tweet us at @bigcommerce anytime. We're happy to help you out.

Comment: I found difficult to create dynamic menus. For side menus we created simply using admin panel. But for top menus and header menus, I'm unable to create. Could you provide samples if any either thru code or any solution to create dynamic menus.